# How can I make a Cydia tweak or theme and how can fix this error

Tags: ios, jailbreak, tweak

Guys 
I have made a new Cydia tweak but the tweak is not done right now because of this error

```
/private/var/root$ dpkg -i iTheme.deb
(Reading database ... 1269 files and directories currently installed.)
Preparing to replace com.yorepo.ijb-erep0.itheme 1.0 (using iTheme.deb) ...
Unpacking replacement com.yorepo.ijb-erep0.itheme ...
dpkg: dependency problems prevent configuration of com.yorepo.ijb-erep0.itheme:
 com.yorepo.ijb-erep0.itheme depends on winterboard; however:
  Package winterboard is not installed.
dpkg: error processing com.yorepo.ijb-erep0.itheme (--install):
 dependency problems - leaving unconfigured
Errors were encountered while processing:
 com.yorepo.ijb-erep0.itheme
```

Every time that I wan't to test my Theme I get this error!
How can I fix this error on windows and how can I make a Cydia tweak,Theme or App without any errors!
Need help I have windows 7 pro!

Answer (score 0):

You need to install Winterboard as Winterboard is listed as a dependency.

> `dpkg: dependency problems prevent configuration of com.yorepo.ijb-erep0.itheme:
>    com.yorepo.ijb-erep0.itheme depends on winterboard; however:
>     Package winterboard is not installed.`

Comment: Yes,I know that I need to install Winterboard but how?

Comment: Go into Cydia and install it or install aptitude and do `apt-get`